# l-lin/angular-datatables, col resize but need no wrap cells content in tables on first load

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Currently I use l-lin/angular-datatables and the col resize plugin in order the user resize width columns. But still I need no wrap content when first load the table so the columns on first load must be the maximum width without any break lines in the content of any of the visible cells in that column.

Do you know a property or plugin for this?

Very important: I know the CSS config property nowrap for datatables but the problem is  when I use it I cant resize with colresize plugin I need the user can reduce width of columns but this property do not allow because no wrap CSS only allow  increase the width of columns but no decrease.

I thought it would be necessary  create a angularjs directive  for setting  the white-space property : nowrap of CSS on firts load.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I`m really very sorry, I'll try to do my best. And also my English is very bad. my heartfelt apologies.

Comment: Hey @user3749378, it is OK! No need to sorry for that :) Just saying, you can always [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36257225/edit) your question (also old ones) to improve them and perhaps attract more views and answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this.